# Impact of process efficiency on global warming potential

Tags: regression, environmental-data

I am an environmental chemistry who is studying the impact of process efficiency improvements of a specific sector on global warming potential (GWP).

A have data from 288 firms and I have already applied multiple regression analysis on this dataset to obtain information on drivers to energy efficiency.

Let GWP of a specific firm i is:  GWPi = Ai + Bi;

where A = CO2 due to electricity used by firm i;
and B = CO2 emitted during the operation of firm i.

Now I know from my data that:

YA = α0 + α1 XA1 + α2 XA2 + α3 XA3;

YB = β0 + β1 XB1 - β2 XB2;

Where YA and YB are respectively the two component of GWP = YA + YB

And XA1, XA2 and XA3 are IV of DV YA, and XB1 and XB2 are IV of DVB.

Now imagine that XA2 and XB2 is the same variable. This variable represents the process efficiency of a firm. How you can see from the model it has opposite sign in the two models. If it increases electricity will increase and as consequence GWP will increase. In the other case, an increasing of this variable will reduce B, and as consequence GWP will reduced.

I would like to study the impact of process efficiency on GWP. In particular, I would like to demonstrate that investing on process efficiency (at cost of increasing energy consumption) would have a positive effect on GWP.

If there is a relationship I would like to quantify the benefit of improving process efficiency on GWP.

Thanks,
Ste